# Is there a way to dynamically display multiple textfields with hooks depends on user selection? (values and onChange)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-hooks

I am setting up a form, and in the form there's a material ui select field ranges from 1 to 50. How am I going to dynamically display/render multiple textfields "Firstname and Lastname" with Hooks in each text fields every time the user select a number?

Ex.
If user chose "3" from the option in the select box, there's expected to be 3 textfields "firstname and lastname" to be rendered.

This is what I have tried so far, I know how to create hooks, with specific textfield but I don't know if I will depend on the user selection.

```
const primary_guest_firstname = useForm('');
const primary_guest_lastname = useForm('');
const primary_guest_adult = useForm(1);

function useForm(init){
  const [ value, setValue ] = useState(init);

  function handleOnChange(e){
    setValue(e.target.value);
  }

  return {
    value,
    onChange: handleOnChange
  }
}

/** sample of select text field with options from 1 - 50... **/
<TextField
 select
 variant="outlined"
 required
 margin="dense"
 fullWidth
 value={primary_guest_adult.value}
 onChange={primary_guest_adult.onChange}
 id="guest"
 label="Adult ( > 12 years)"
 name="guest"
>
 <MenuItem value="1">1</MenuItem>
 <MenuItem value="2">2</MenuItem>
 <MenuItem value="3">3</MenuItem>
  ...
 <MenuItem value="50">50</MenuItem>
</TextField>


/** I should render dynamic textfield here... 
if the user selected "3", there should be 3 textfields 
generated here with hook.. **/

<TextField
  variant="outlined"
  required
  margin="dense" 
  fullWidth
  id="firstName"
  label="First Name"
  name="firstName"
  value={primary_guest_firstname.value}
  onChange={primary_guest_firstname.onChange}
/>
<TextField
  variant="outlined"
  required
  margin="dense" 
  fullWidth
  id="lastName"
  label="Last Name"
  name="lastName"
  value={primary_guest_lastname.value}
  onChange={primary_guest_lastname.onChange}
/>
```

I appreciate your help :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by creating an array of required values in the state array.

Instead of single state, you would have an array of states, which needs to be set and read accordingly.

Demo:

```js
const { render } = ReactDOM;
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

function useForm(init){
  const [ value, setValue ] = useState(init);

  function handleOnChange(e){
    setValue(e.target.value);
  }

  return {
    value,
    onChange: handleOnChange
  }
}

function useForms(reqNum) {
  const initial = [...Array(reqNum)].map(()=>({ firstName: "", lastName: "" }));
  const [values, setValues] = useState(initial);
  function handleChange(event, name, changedIndex) {
    const { target: { value }} = event;
    setValues(values => values.map((val, index) => {
      if(changedIndex === index) {
        return {
          ...val,
          [name]: value,
        }
      }
      return val;
    }));
  }
  function handleNumChange(changedNum) {
    const changedValues = [...Array(+changedNum)].map(()=>({ firstName: "", lastName: "" }));
    setValues(changedValues);
  }
  return {
    values,
    handleChange,
    handleNumChange,
  }
}

const NameFields = ({ values }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {values.map((value, index) =>  (
      <div key={index}>
        <input placeholder={`First Name ${index+1}`} value={value.firstName} onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, "firstName", index)} />
        <input placeholder={`Last Name ${index+1}`} value={value.lastName} onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, "lastName", index)} />
      </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

const App = () => {
  const options = [1,2,3,4,5];
  const {value: numberOfAdults, onChange: setNumberOfAdults} = useForm(1);
  const { values, handleChange, handleNumChange } = useForms(numberOfAdults);
  useEffect(() => {
    handleNumChange(numberOfAdults);
  }, [numberOfAdults]);
  return (
    <main>
      <select value={numberOfAdults} onChange={setNumberOfAdults}>
        {options.map((option)=>(
          <option value={option} key={option}>{option}</option>
        ))}
      </select>
      <NameFields values={values} />
    </main>
  );
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root" />
```